# How to have two elements with same width and margin but expand according to bigger text

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

- Two elements within a container always take up half the space minus the gap between them.
- When one element's text content is bigger than half the space, it expands and takes more space.

example:
[image]

what I tried:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
}

.block {
  flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 8px);
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width:0 ;
}

.block:first-child {
 margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum ffffffff ffffffffff</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

the text does not push the flex container, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if is this exactly what you want, but maybe `display: inline-flex` and `flex-grow: 1` without forcing a specific width on `.block`.

Please, check it:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
}

.block {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
}

.block:first-child {
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum ffffffff ffffffffff</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

But, of course, if the text of one of the blocks become too big, it will break down to next line, unless you apply some kind of ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

Each flex item will take up as much space as needed.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.flex-block {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="flex-block">lorem ipsum dolar something</div>
  <div class="flex-block">some more lorem ipsum but this time make it longer</div>
</div>
```

If you want to limit the flex item's width to a max width of say 50% in this example, you can add flex: 1; to the item as well as align-self: stretch; so that each item becomes the same height regardless of inner content